# installing PHP's PEAR got into a loop (Windows)

Tags: pear

In [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZ20A.png)screenshot the CMD was looping with these 13 option while giving the option to just press ENTER to accept all, the only way to stop it is by pressing CTRL+C, after which I had the chance to capture what is looping. In the screen there was:

`**ERROR** 
Please, enter the php.exe path.` which I did anyway.

As in the last line, `c:\php7\php.exe go-pear.phar`did not work. Everything is in place. I could not find such a thing like : another CLI php.exe requirement in the context of installing PEAR, so I expect php.exe is the one meant for that. c:\php7 was added to the PATH, even though I never needed to do so in the past.

Does anyone have any suggestion to get the installation of PEAR continue in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same loop 'error', but I've realized that I need to complete point number 13 (that also looks empty in your image).

Make sure that you have installed PHP previously (native or trough XMAPP). You need to find out where does php.exe file is located. In my case (native) is exactly where I chosen. After that the prompt will show you (again) same list but notice that now point 13 will show you a path (again where php.exe is) and finally you press Enter.

**Note:** In this case you can see that I installed PHP (manually) on `C:\Server\bin\PHP\`

[image: pear installation]